# How to select a table from Mysql Database (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select a table from my database, but I don't know how to do this, and i'm not good in searching google.
The code that i have now: 
`$query = "SELECT * FROM table";`

```
echo $query;
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

EDIT: I'm using PDO for my connection

Comment: Start by reading the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php or http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can find this everywhere on the web.
This is the basic code to display data from your database in a table:

```
require ('connection_to_db.php'); 

try {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = $pdo -> query($sql);
$result->execute(); 
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Something went wrong";
$e->getMessage();
exit;
}

echo "<table width='100%' border='1'>";

while($row = $result -> fetch() ) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['table']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: This is PDO by the way:-)